# Getting error while installing scikit-surprise

Tags: build-tools, python-3.12

C:\research>pip install scikit-surprise
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting scikit-surprise
Using cached scikit-surprise-1.1.3.tar.gz (771 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0.0 in c:\users\kunwar ishwar singh\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from scikit-surprise) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\users\kunwar ishwar singh\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from scikit-surprise) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3.2 in c:\users\kunwar ishwar singh\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from scikit-surprise) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-surprise
Building wheel for scikit-surprise (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [129 lines of output]
C:\Users\Kunwar Ishwar Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vzdxtnj7\scikit-surprise_b2dfabe34f7d4597976cc44f79078b89\setup.py:65: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
!!

```
          ********************************************************************************
          Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(["numpy>=1.17.3"])
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\accuracy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\builtin_datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\dump.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\trainset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
  copying surprise\model_selection\search.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
  copying surprise\model_selection\split.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
  copying surprise\model_selection\validation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
  copying surprise\model_selection\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\model_selection
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\algo_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\baseline_only.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\knns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\predictions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\random_pred.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  running egg_info
  writing scikit_surprise.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to scikit_surprise.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to scikit_surprise.egg-info\entry_points.txt
  writing requirements to scikit_surprise.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to scikit_surprise.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'scikit_surprise.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.md'
  writing manifest file 'scikit_surprise.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  C:\Users\Kunwar Ishwar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:207: _Warning: Package 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
  !!

          ********************************************************************************
          ############################
          # Package would be ignored #
          ############################
          Python recognizes 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' as an importable package[^1],
          but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

          This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
          package, please make sure that 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' is explicitly added
          to the `packages` configuration field.

          Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
          (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
          instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

          You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

          - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

          If you don't want 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' to be distributed and are
          already explicitly excluding 'surprise.prediction_algorithms' via
          `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
          you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
          combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

          You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

          - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


          [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                directory, all directories are treated like packages.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    check.warn(importable)
  copying surprise\similarities.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\similarities.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\co_clustering.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\optimize_baselines.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\slope_one.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\co_clustering.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\optimize_baselines.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\slope_one.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\surprise\prediction_algorithms
  running build_ext
  building 'surprise.similarities' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\surprise
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Kunwar Ishwar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsurprise/similarities.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\surprise/similarities.obj
  similarities.c
  C:\Users\Kunwar Ishwar Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
  surprise/similarities.c(15478): warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12
  surprise/similarities.c(24414): error C2039: 'curexc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/pystate.h(115): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  surprise/similarities.c(24417): error C2039: 'curexc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/pystate.h(115): note: see declaration of '_ts'
  surprise/similarities.c(24531): warning C4013: '_PyUnicode_Ready' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  surprise/similarities.c(25020): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
  surprise/similarities.c(26982): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
  surprise/similarities.c(27037): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
  surprise/similarities.c(27254): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
  surprise/similarities.c(27309): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
  surprise/similarities.c(27450): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
  surprise/similarities.c(27505): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
  surprise/similarities.c(27856): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
  C:\Program Files\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-surprise
Running setup.py clean for scikit-surprise
Failed to build scikit-surprise
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-surprise, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

C:\research>

tried installing build tools for c++
upgraded setuptool